# UICollectionView didSelect not called in a specific view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uistackview

I'm hurt to an edge case I guess?

Here is my current view hierarchy of the my problematic top most view controller.

UIView-> UIScrollView-> UIView-> UIStackView-> UICollectionView

My stack view contain multiple arranged views. 
What happen is that for some reason my (non scrollable) `UICollectionView` is not responding to its delegate didSelectRow method.

It receive touch event, I can even see `shoudlHighightCell` being called. But impossible to get the didSelect method called.

It's a reusable component I'm using maybe more than 10 times all across my apps, but in this specific hierarchy, it's not working.

I've tried to remove some gesture, to fiddle with delay touch of the parent `UIScrollView`, but it's still not working.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your code? just confirm that the delegate assignment is in place.

Comment: @Satish It's not my question, but I think that he's already assigned the delegate since he said his component works well in other hierarchies.

Comment: Hi, I'm also struggling with this problem. For my case, the hierarchy of views are like this:

UIView -> UIView -> UICollectionView

and even though I added the ViewController as a delegate, it only calls didHighlightItemAt :(

Please anybody helps us!

+ While I'm moving this one to comment, I got one solution for it. If doing 3d touch to that CollectionViewCell, it recognizes touch as 'select'.